# (0xc0000005) 'Access violation' In debug output with no errors

Tags: c#

I had a totally workable program until I tried changing the .Net Framework from 4.5 to 4.0 to 3.5 and then back to 4.5. Now it doesn't want to even launch with no errors in the error list, just this output which shows:

```
The thread 0xc14 has exited with code 259 (0x103).
The thread 0xb7c has exited with code 259 (0x103).
The thread 0xd40 has exited with code 259 (0x103).
'SAMP_Worker.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: SAMP_Worker.vshost.exe): Loaded 'C:\Users\Dmetrey\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\SAMP_Worker\SAMP_Worker\bin\Debug\SAMP_Worker.exe'. Symbols loaded.
A first chance exception of type 'System.IndexOutOfRangeException' occurred in SAMP_Worker.exe
'SAMP_Worker.vshost.exe' (CLR v4.0.30319: SAMP_Worker.vshost.exe): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Configuration\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Configuration.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
The program '[6120] SAMP_Worker.vshost.exe' has exited with code -1073741819 (0xc0000005) 'Access violation'.
```

I guess I could try making a different Win form, generating all the functons my old program had and then just paste the old code. But isn't there an easier way of solving this?

Comment: I'm seeing a `System.IndexOutOfRangeException` in your output there. The way to solve that is to find where your code is trying to access, you know, and index that's not in range :).

Comment: Looks like it does actually start... but crashes in an early stage, due to that IndexOutOfRangeException. Maybe add some `Console.Error.WriteLine(...)` statements, so you can pinpoint where the Exception takes place?

Comment: Thank you, i guess i was so blind there, it was all becouse a text file had less lines then the program was trying to read. Its just that before i had an actual error comeup that would show be where the code was not able to run. Im thinking its becouse i dont have all the optional features installed, im using VS2013.